# Android WebView file chooser custom path

Tags: android, webview, filechooser

I am creating an app able to capture images. I also have a web service where users are able to share their photos. I am oppening a WebView where page with upload form is located, everything works as expected (I'm using code found at stackoverflow). Only thing is - by default Android open dialog with multiple apps which can select particular image to upload. Can I make my app-path (one in which my app save captured images) default path for built-in file chooser? Or is there posibiity to use by default some other than built-in file chooser where I can set my path? This is my code for image chooser:

```
public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture){
   mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;  
   Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);  
   i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);  
   i.setType("image/*");  
   MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(
       Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), 
       MainActivity.FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);

}
```

Thanks in advance